# Determinant of Frobenius action on the exterior power on cohomology

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, determinant, elliptic-curves

Given an elliptic curve $E$, the Frobenius action $\mathrm{Frob}$, and $\mathrm{det}(1-\mathrm{Frob}_E T | H^1(E))$, how do we find an expression for:

$$\mathrm{det}(1-\mathrm{Frob}_X T | \wedge^2 (H^1(E) \otimes H^1(E)))$$

for $X=(E \times E)/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, the abelian surface with 16 singular points which correspond to the 2-torsion points of $E$.

This seems to be an exercise in linear algebra but I am somewhat muddled with how operations work over exterior powers!

Comment: A rhetorical question:  "Why the close vote?" It's a rhetorical question, because I think I know "why", but I do not think it is warranted in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure at all if that's what you're looking for, but you're looking whether $\det{\Lambda^2f}$ can be determined as a function of $\det{f}$ when $f$ is an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space?

It would be an algebraic relationship, so (assuming it exists) it would be enough to show it over the field of complex numbers for a dense subset of $f$, e.g. $f$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

But when $f$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$, with eigenvectors $e_i$, then the $e_i \wedge e_j$, $i < j$, are a basis of eigenvectors (with values $\alpha_i\alpha_j$) of $\Lambda^2f$. Therefore, $\det{\Lambda^2f} = \prod_{i < j}{\alpha_i\alpha_j}=\prod_{i=1}^n{\alpha_i^{n-i}}\prod_{j=1}^n{\alpha_j^{j-1}}=(\det{f})^{n-1}$.

So, in general, $\det{\Lambda^2f}=(\det{f})^{n-1}$, where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space $f$ is defined on.

Note that this would of course work for free modules over a commutative ring with unity.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Right, gotcha! So the next question is how would we relate $\mathrm{det}(f|H^1(E))$ to $\mathrm{det}(f|H^1(E) \otimes H^1(E))$? Assuming that $f$ acts via the matrix $A$ on $H^1(E)$, could it be argued that $f$ acts via $A \oplus A$ on $H^1(E) \otimes H^1(E)$? In this case, we would have $\mathrm{det}(f|H^1(E) \otimes H^1(E))$=$\mathrm{det}(f|H^1(E))^2$. Also in this situation, is it right to say that the Frobenius action acts on a vector space of dimension $2$?

Comment: @chives: The same argument shows that actually $\det{f^{\otimes 2}}=(\det{f})^{2n}$ when $f$ is an endomorphism of a $n$-dimensional space. Indeed, $f$ acts as $A \otimes A$ (a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix) on $H^1(E) \otimes H^1(E)$.

Comment: Ah yes of course! My bad - forgot about the Kronecker product! Thank you very much